# How to change Sharepoint admistrator password

Tags: sharepoint

I chose not to put this on ServerFault as I am asking it as a user, not a network administrator. I have a Sharepoint server set up at my office and I can log in as admin (System Account). However, I can't change my password. How does one change the administrator password when logged in via a browser.

Some version info

```
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_extenderversion:SR|15.0.0.4420
```

Note: googling the problem [did not help](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=sharepoint%20change%20admin%20password)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint when installed as a Server Farm is Active Directory integrated. To change your password, you would change it the same way a regular password, through Ctrl + Alt + Del and the "Change Password" button, or by having an Active Directory administrator change it for you.

However, you should use caution while doing this! There are several service accounts that were used when setting up SharePoint for running various background services. Best practices are to not use those accounts for logging into SharePoint or the local server (although you can).

In modern versions of SharePoint, those service accounts can be set up as "[Managed Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262502(v=office.15).aspx)". You can configure and change these passwords through Central Administration->Security->Configure Managed Accounts. Best practice is for these passwords to be randomized and managed by the system, but you can manually reset them here and have them propagate across SharePoint. (Note that pre-2010 versions of SharePoint don't have this functionality)

You may want to check out the [SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) site as well. Lots of good stuff there for creating and maintaining SharePoint!